# use variable in command bash file in mac

Tags: bash, macos, sh, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I created a bash script for show notification 5 seconds in mac OS.

```
#!/bin/bash

arr[0]="0"
arr[1]="1"
arr[2]="2"
arr[3]="3"
arr[4]="4"
arr[5]="5"
arr[6]="6"

while true; do
 
    rand=$[$RANDOM % ${#arr[@]}]
    text=${arr[$rand]}
    
    osascript -e 'display notification '"$text"' with title "hello"'

    sleep 5
done
```

but show notification with title hello and description $text.
How can use the $text variable in this command?

Comment: what do you see when you surround your `osascript` line with `set -x; osascript ..... ; set +x` ? Good luck.

Comment: @RasoulMiri : Why is it tagged _zsh_ if there is no zsh involved?

Answer (score 4):

Pass the value of `"$text"` as an argument to a static script.

```
osascript -e 'on run argv' \
          -e 'display notification (item 1 of argv) with title "hello"' \
          -e 'end run' "$text"
```

or

```
osascript -e 'on run argv
display notification (item 1 of argv) with title "hello"
end run' "$text"
```

As an aside, `$[...]` is an extremely old and extremely obsolete form of arithmetic expansion. Use `$((...))` instead.